# Call Block's method in Helper

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, helper

I have **Block** class

```
class Abc_AddressManager_Block_Address_Book extends 

Mage_Customer_Block_Address_Book {
       public function getAdditionalAddresses() {
          $addresses = $this->getCustomer()->getAddresses();
          return $addresses;
      }
}
```

And **Helper** class

```
class Abc_AddressManager_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {...}
```

want to call **getAdditionalAddresses()** in **Helper**

Have tried

```
$addressBookBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('Abc_AddressManager_Block_Address_Book');
$_pAddsses = $addressBookBlock->getAdditionalAddresses();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should not call block methods in helpers.
Try it the other way around.
Declare your method in the helper and call it in your block using

```
Mage::helper('helper/alias_here')->abc();
```

Comment: Thanks for attention, not possible, as you can see in updated post, it is returning current customers address, then in helper, I have to load my customer, which I don't want.

Comment: you still have to load the customer in the helper. Because using it with getBlockSingleton() will most probably get an error because `getCustomer` may be null.